# How to pass a struct to another package?

Tags: go

This is a very watered down version of what I'm trying to do but please help me with the following scenario:

PackageA.go

```
package A

import "B"

type TestStruct struct {
  Atest string
}

func Test() {
  test := TestStruct{"Hello World"}
  B.Test(test)
}
```

PackageB.go

```
package B

import "fmt"

func Test(test TestStruct) {
  fmt.Println(test.Atest)
}
```

This fails with `undefined: test` when it hits Package B

Basically I'm having issues passing structs from one package to another or even passing variables that act as pointers to other structs or functions.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: `B` would need to import `A` to know about the `TestStruct` type. But then you have a circular dependency, and you might as well merge the two packages (or at least shuffle some code around).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reorganize your code as:

a.go

```
package a

import "b"

func Test() {
    test := b.TestStruct{"Hello World"}
    b.Test(test)
}
```

b.go

```
package b

import "fmt"

type TestStruct struct {
    Atest string
}

func Test(test TestStruct) {
    fmt.Println(test.Atest)
}
```